# Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory. C#

Tags: c#, navigation, directory

I have searched and can not use the generally accepted answer to solve my problem.

In c# code behind on my Site.Master c# page I have this code that creates a bootstrap menu item on the fly.

```
R1.Text = 
    "<li class='dropdown'>" +
        "<a runat='server' href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' role='button' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>My Account<span class='caret'></span></a>" +
        "<ul class='dropdown-menu' >" +
                "<li><a runat='server' href='../Account/Register'>Register</a></li>" +
                "<li class='divider'></li>" +
                "<li><a runat='server' href='../Account/Login'>Login</a></li>" +
                "<li class='divider'></li>" +
                "<li><a runat='server' href='../TermsConditions'>Terms and Conditions</a></li>" +
                "<li class='divider'></li>" +
                "<li><a runat='server' href='../PrivacyPolicy'>Privacy Policy</a></li>" +
         "</ul>" +
    "</li>";
```

And the corresponding aspx page has this in part of creating the bootstrap navigation....

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
        <asp:Label ID="R1" runat="server" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

So `href='../TermsConditions'` and `../PrivacyPolicy` work fine but `href='../Account/Register'` and `href='../Account/Login'` both give the

**Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.** *Error.*

I tried using the friendly url `~` and this generates a `404 error of page not found /~/Account/Register`

I was thinking it was route permissions so my RouteConfig =

```
public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        //var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        //settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
        //routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);

        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls();

    }
}
```

And I have my /Account web.Config =

```
<location>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>

<location path="Manage.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

So what am I missing?

Here is the stacktrace. Can someone tell me where this error is occurring?

[HttpException (0x80004005): The 'href' property had a malformed URL: Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory..]
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl.PreProcessRelativeReferenceAttribute(HtmlTextWriter writer, String attribName) +188
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor.RenderAttributes(HtmlTextWriter writer) +93
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer) +41
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +20
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +66
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   ASP.site_master.__Renderform1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in C:\Users\Michael Wood\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Thinair\Thinair\Site.Master:0
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +268
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +9856836
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +32
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +53
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +66
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +40
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +128
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +13
   System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +12
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +66
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +128
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +29
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +66
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1303

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reference something that is outside the root of the site.

say you have a folder structure like so

```
C:\WWW
├───images
├───content
└───styles
```

Lets say that C:\www is your top directory and that you have a webpage there.
In that webpage, you try and reference something like so

```
 <a href='../otherpage.html'>click me</a>
```

The above is trying to reference a page (located at `C:\otherpage.html`) that is outside of the root directory (`C:\www`) and thus giving you this error

Comment: No, I am referencing the login and register pages under /Account/ that are generated with user authentication out of the box when you create a new web site. I could understand the error if I was calling a page above the root. The only thing I can think is that login or register are calling a page above the root but I wouldn't imaging that to be the case , out of the box.

Comment: Are you sure that all references / links do not start at the root?

Comment: I am in the process of going through the entire project searching for "../" and this is going to be a long process as bootstrap and jquery have ../ and ../../ in their code. I would think there has to be a better way to find this reference that is throwing this error. The only references I am keeping is those in the <img> tags that use ../Images/image.jpg. If you know a better or faster way to find what is tripping this error, I am all ears.